# Struts and Spring Configuratuion

Tags: java, spring-mvc, struts, spring-data

I have a Huge Project where some part is Struts1 some Spring.

I have a Dao Class in spring as :

```
@Component
public class CouchDao {
@Autowired(required = false)
ICouchbaseTemplateInterface iCouchbaseTemplateInterface;

public List<Couch> getUnExpiredForClient(int client) {
    Query query = new Query();
    CouchList=iCouchbaseTemplateInterface.findAllOrderBypostionAcrossVerticalDesc(query);
    List<Couch> CouchList=new ArrayList<Couch>();
    try {
        CouchList = iCouchbaseTemplateInterface.findAllOrderBypostionAcrossVerticalDesc(query);//CouchBase Query
    }
```

This Works fine for a Spring Class. But when i Call the same with Struts as follows:

```
CouchDao.getUnExpiredForClient(0);
```

The Try part in getUnExpiredForClient() thorws Null Pointer Exception.

My action-servlet.xml is as follows for same:

```
<bean name="/**" class="**.APIAction">
    <property name="CouchDao" ref="CouchDao" />

</bean>
```

Kindly Help With same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that with struts you are "losing" the Spring context. Autowired annotation initialize the bean ICouchbaseTemplateInterface for the spring context, but not for struts.

For example, since you have declared in the struts action xml file the bean CouchDao, struts framework is available to inject the bean CouchDao, but it has not recognize the Autowired annotation, so ICouchbaseTemplateInterface is not initialized and a NullPointerException is thrown. Try to inject also that bean in the xml.

Sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: I am new to Struts. It would be great if you could help with same.

Comment: Could you post also all your action-servlet.xml and the APIAction class?

Comment: Action Servlet: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

The class will remain same.